# Mercurial doesn't ignore files in directory I specify

Tags: mercurial, ignore, hgignore

I have mercurial repository. There is .hgignore file:

```
λ ~/workspace/kompgrafika/nurbs/ cat .hgignore 
syntax: regexp
^Makefile
^bin/.*$
CMakeFiles/.*$
^CMakeCache\.txt
^cmake_install\.cmake
```

There is directory named CMakeFiles that I want to ignore:

```
λ ~/workspace/kompgrafika/nurbs/ tree CMakeFiles 
CMakeFiles
├── 3dfractals.dir
│   ├── build.make
│   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   ├── CXX.includecache
│   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   ├── depend.internal
│   ├── depend.make
│   ├── flags.make
│   ├── link.txt
│       ├── progress.make
│   └── src
│       ├── DisplayControl.cpp.o
│       ├── Drawer.cpp.o
│       ├── main.cpp.o
│       ├── PointFileReader.cpp.o
│       ├── PointGenerator.cpp.o
│       └── Program.cpp.o
├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
├── cmake.check_cache
├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
├── CMakeOutput.log
├── CMakeSystem.cmake
├── CMakeTmp
│   └── CMakeFiles
│       └── cmTryCompileExec.dir
├── CompilerIdC
│   ├── a.out
│   └── CMakeCCompilerId.c
├── CompilerIdCXX
│   ├── a.out
│   └── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
├── Makefile2
├── Makefile.cmake
├── progress.marks
└── TargetDirectories.txt
```

7 directories, 31 files

But running `hg status` it does not ignore 3dfractals.dir for some reason.

```
λ ~/workspace/kompgrafika/nurbs/ hg st
A .hgignore
A docs/pol_10.wings
? CMakeFiles/3dfractals.dir/src/DisplayControl.cpp.o
? CMakeFiles/3dfractals.dir/src/Drawer.cpp.o
? CMakeFiles/3dfractals.dir/src/PointFileReader.cpp.o
? CMakeFiles/3dfractals.dir/src/PointGenerator.cpp.o
? CMakeFiles/3dfractals.dir/src/Program.cpp.o
? CMakeFiles/3dfractals.dir/src/main.cpp.o
```

I am using:

```
λ ~/workspace/kompgrafika/nurbs/ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.0.2+5-1f9f9b4c2923)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2011 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I also tried changing `CMakeFiles/.*$` to `^CMakeFiles$`. No results.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it works here:

```
$ cat .hgignore
syntax:regexp
^Makefile
^bin/.*$
CMakeFiles/.*$
^CMakeCache\.txt
^cmake_install\.cmake
$ hg init
$ mkdir -p $(dirname CMakeFiles/3dfractals.dir/src/DisplayControl.cpp.o)
$ touch CMakeFiles/3dfractals.dir/src/DisplayControl.cpp.o
$ touch CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache
$ hg status
? .hgignore
$ hg status -A
? .hgignore
I CMakeFiles/3dfractals.dir/src/DisplayControl.cpp.o
I CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache
```

This is with Mercurial 2.0.2+59, so it should work the same as your version.

One thing that can trip up `hg status` in the way you see is the [**inotify** extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/InotifyExtension). As mentioned on its wiki page, it's still to be considered experimental because it's [still buggy](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/InotifyBug). Check for inotify with

```
$ hg showconfig extensions.inotify
```

and disable it if necessary. If the extension is loaded from your own configuration file (check with `hg showconfig --debug`) then you can just remove the line that loads it. If it's loaded in a system-wide config file that you cannot change, then add

```
[extensions]
inotify = !
```

to your own config file to disable it.

Comment: I did `rm -rf CMakeFiles` and make (to create that dir again). Then ran `hg status` and the directory is gone from the list. Some kind of cache bug?

Comment: Nah, shouldn't be — we don't cache information about the `.hgignore` file. Does `hg showconfig extensions` mention `inotify` by chance? That's a filesystem monitor extension that might mess things up to create the situation you just saw.

Comment: Yes it does. Seems like removing that extension solves the problem.

Comment: There we go! I've expanded the answer with more info about the inotify extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows, but usually

> CMakeFiles/*

would do the trick for me...